# Is this a valid design of an audio power amplifier with bipolar transistors and no capacitors?

Tags: transistors, diy, power-amplifier

I'm concerned about input/output capacitors in power amplifiers and their destructive impact on the sound-wave.

In my understanding, for simple transistor DIY amplifiers you'll need a really big capacitor (normally available only as electrolytic capacitor) to prevent square wave at low frequencies from being bent towards saw-like shape.

I am also interested in building my own transistor amplifier (10W should be more than enough) with simple schematic. I'd like to use small amount of parts.

I came up with a plan and would like to ask if I made any serious mistake here. (I understand that I'll need to add some small capacitors between op-amp V+ and V- to ground to reduce noise.)

Drawing of planned power amplifier:

[image: drawing of planned power amplifier]

**Update:**

Adding new drawing according to comments (removed second OP-amp, added diodes between bases hope that helps for temperature compensation).

[image: new drawing of planned power amplifier]

Comment: Building a class B amplifier without having looked into existing designs and how they deal with crossover distortion will have far more destructive impact on the sound wave than an electrolytic capacitor theoretically could, which it doesn't really. Have you tried simulating it! It helps everybody to draw the schematic with +ve voltages to the top, and bias currents flowing downwards.

Comment: I expect this to work as a class AB amplifier, not class B.

Comment: Yes I tried simulating it, it behaves so perfectly that I'm in doubts.

Comment: Ah! I see. The extra voltage from R3/R4 R6/R7 puts both output devices into conduction. There's no control of the overlap against tempertaute and rail voltage. There's no overall feedback to control against VBE non-linearity. Have you simulated the distortion? I ask again, have you looked at any amplifier designs and the theory of solving crossover problems. You are simply reinventing a square wheel that many designers have already spent decades hammering into a round shape, and publishing designs and commentary on them.

Comment: Without temperature compensation, it will go in thermal runaway and burn the output devices.

Comment: Yeah I've tried some designs, wasn't easy because I noticed often people publish non-working schemes and also most of them have capacitors. I'm not sure what do you mean by crossover problems (I don't have a crossover). No I haven't simulated distortion (don't know how to do this).

Comment: "it behaves so perfectly that I'm in doubts". Well, _I_ have doubts: without any feedback, the crossover distortion will be tremendous.

Comment: Since you have bipolar supplies, you need only two capacitors in a standard design, one on the input and one to prevent the opamp's input offset voltage from being multiplied by 100 and driven across the speaker, which your circuit absolutely *will* do.  Circuit parameters can be adjusted such that the cap values are small enough that they can be high-quality film types.  With decent input stage design, you do not need any output coupling capacitor.

Comment: @DavideAndrea why there's no distortion in oscilloscope during simulation then? Distortion was present, but after I added R7 and R4 it was gone. What do you mean by feedback? I thought I have a feedback in R5 and R2.

Comment: @bobflux would that be enough for temperature compensation: [link](https://pasteimg.com/images/2021/10/02/thermal.jpg) ?

Comment: No that can't work, you have to set the voltage between bases of output transistors. Also the schematic with the opamps won't work, it only "works" in simulation because simulated opamps are identical, that's not the case with real opamps.

Comment: @Testik The output is not included in a global negative feedback loop. This means it is running "open-loop." The simulation uses identical models for both opamps, for example, and that already isn't realistic.

Comment: This is a terrible design for an audio amplifier, where did this design come from? There are plenty of proven designs, why not use one of those? If you would use this design because you're worried about the capacitors, you still have a lot to learn. Study the schematic of any modern quality amplifier and note how there's usually only a few small caps in the signal path near the input. With a symmetrical pwoer supply, it is trivial not to have an output capacitor. Do realize that output DC voltage protection might be a good idea.

Comment: @Testik: [This is crossover distortion.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_distortion)  It has to do with switching from one active device to the other.  It has nothing to do with the crossover used to split the audio signal for different speakers.

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing some emitter degeneration in the output transistors. With a large number of stepwise improvements like this, you'll eventually end up with something like a reasonable design. Try looking for better sources than random 'people on the internet'. Search for 'crimson electric audio amplifier schematic' for instance.

Comment: as I understood I can achieve global negative feedback loop by detaching right leg of my 47k resistor and attaching it to the final output, right?
btw I've heard some audiophiles say that global negative feedback loop is a bad thing and it "destroys music" and they try to make amplifiers without one

Comment: @Testik I'd like to see their arguments about why global NFB destroys music. Instead, it corrects for offset (important, most especially when you are ***not*** using capacitors, by the way) and signal-dependent gain errors (distortion.) I'm pretty sure that their arguments will be based upon very, very subjective and personal worldviews.

Comment: @jonk they usually claim that the difference is clearly audible, sometimes this document cited: https://www.passdiy.com/pdf/distortion_feedback.pdf also this (page 59): https://next-tube.com/articles/Cheever/cheever.pdf

Comment: @Testik I have been through these claims so many times already that I'm no longer willing to waste further precious time on them. If you want, digest what they say and see if you can convince me. I don't mind you spending your time and them presenting me with a cogent argument here. I'll deal with an informed comment from you. I just won't spend my time arguing with a PDF or two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. That circuit is not valid might work perfectly only in a simulation. Real world components have tolerances such as op amps have offset voltage - both op amps might want to drive their own input pins to different voltages but they can't do that now.

And since you have a dual voltage to begin with, you don't need output capacitors as the output can be DC coupled. Just use a single op-amp and include the emitter followers at the output to boost current and take the feedback from there. Usually good results are achieved by proper biasing of the transistor bases and finding a suitable quiescent emitter bias current via emitter resistors to minimize crossover distortion.

Comment: thanks, I updated the post with a new picture please tell if that's better (I understood that I'll need to change 3k resistors later to fix crossover distortions)

Comment: That buffer stage is still driven in open loop, outside the feedback. Also you can't expect the Vbe drops to match the diode drops. Is there a reason you don't drive the middle point of diodes with the op amp directly?

Comment: thanks, I found a scheme of emitter follower where middle point driven with op amp directly: https://www.nutsvolts.com/uploads/wygwam/NV_0801_Marston_FIGURE11.jpg I think it's not complete (no diodes or resistors), so this is my version: https://pasteimg.com/images/2021/10/03/3rd.jpg
I hope now I've got the general feedback loop now?
I can explain why I'm placing 47k/1k resistors: it's because I expect input signal to be of 250mV amplitude so I need some gain, I hope this doesn't "kill" the feedback.

And what should I place instead of diodes to match the "Vbe drop"?

Comment: @Testik That last diagram at the bottom of your question also has problems. Tell me what happens when you try and drive towards either rail, for example. Not hand-waving. Work out the details of how your output stage gets its recombination currents. I want to see *numbers* and *sources*. Also, you won't get \$10\:\text{W}\$ from \$\pm 12\:\text{V}\$ rails into \$8\:\Omega\$. (That's just a basic sniff-test result.)